# Как получить данные стоящие ПЕРЕД символом?

Tags: php, переменные

Здравствуйте, ХешКод :) Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить значение стоящее перед определённым символом? Пример, есть число:

```
0.35
```

Мне надо получить 0 и занести его в переменную, или такой пример:

```
234.23
```

Занести 234 в переменную... Как такое можно реализовать? А всё что после точки(включая саму точку), просто игнорировалось бы.

Comment: (int) поможет  
http://ideone.com/p3tiBT

Comment: Вопрос стоило озаглавить примерно так: Получение целой части от числа в php

Answer (score 2):

Работа только с числами? Или это было только для примера?

Если необходимо работать так же со строками (например AA.X - получить AA), то тогда можно использовать [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php) вместе с  [strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php).

Данный способ можно применить и к числам, но если работа будет вестись только с числами, то тогда  в зависимости от целей лучше использовать другое. Это может быть и приведение к целому, либо сначала округление в нужную сторону, а затем уже приведение. Про приведение типов лучше почитать на [офсайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php). Там как раз есть почти ваш пример.

Answer (score 1):

если только числа, то int, а если любые строки с разделителем, то первую часть можно взять так:

```
<?php

$string="Hi:there";
$first=array_shift(explode(':',$string));
print $first;
```

http://codepad.org/P62p5iOi

если разделитель всегда точка и первая часть заведомо не содержит разделителя директорий (/ и мб в винде \ )то можно так:

```
<?php

$string="Hi.there";
$first=pathinfo($string,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
print $first;
```

http://codepad.org/C9G5MUGX

Comment: По последнему: [не работает](http://codepad.org/rf6wZJVp). Т.е. работает не так как надо - возвращает все кроме последней части, а надо, насколько понял, только первую часть

Comment: я не учитывал множественное разделение :)  у последнего случая весьма узкое применение

Answer (score 0):

если только числа, то:

```
$int = 32.56;
$result = floor($int);
echo $result;
```

Если и строки тоже то с explode, как описано выше...